# List returning unique values from another list in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I need to create a new list that contains unique values from another list, also order has to be maintained.
My code:

```
def unique_elements(a):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] not in a[i+1:] and a[i-1::-1] :
                newlist.append(a[i])
    return newlist
```

Output is:

```
unique_elements([1,2,2,3,4,3])
[1, 2, 4, 3]
```

I am getting semi correct result, in that order is not maintained. Correct output should be:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Could someone please let me know where I am going wrong.

I got this solution from other post:

```
def unique_elements(a):
    newlist = []
    for i in a:
        if i not in newlist:
                newlist.append(i)
    return newlist
```

Also, I am not yet exposed to SETs in Python. So could someone let me know if my original code can work?

Comment: *Also, I am not yet exposed to SETs in Python. So could someone let me know if my original code can work?* The linked question has sets

Comment: `set` are not ordered so in your case they will not serve the purpose. Find my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def unique_elements(a):
    newlist = []
    for i in a:
        if i not in newlist:
            newlist.append(i)
    return newlist


xyz = [1,1,2,4,6,2,2,4,5]

print(unique_elements(xyz))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 6, 5]
```